# Update API in laravel 5.7

Tags: api, laravel-5.7

I have create API of update my project details, I test it in POSTMAN app it shows the success message but there no effect in the database.
Here are my code:

ProjectsController.php

```
public function UpdateProject($id)
{
    $data = Input::all();
    $q = Project::where('id',$id)->update($data);
    return response()->json([
        'code' => SUCCESS,
        'message' => 'Project data update successfully'
    ]);
}
```

api.php

```
Route::post('UpdateProject/{id}','ProjectsController@UpdateProject');
```

Postman - [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQkg8.png).

output in postman:

```
{
    "code": "200",
    "message": "Project data update successfylly"
}
```

Can anyone help me out?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to check all input details closely , it also comes with token when you submit the form so you need to save all details except token

Change this

```
$data = Input::all();
```

to this

```
$data = Input::except('_token');
```

I hope this resolves the issue.

Comment: Glade i helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

in your model add **fillable** :

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'project_group_id','number','ROM','address','city','state','zip','start_date','end_date','duration','description','timeline_type','project_type_id','project_category_id','office_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to run the `->save()` method after updating the data:

```
public function UpdateProject($id)
{
    $data = Input::all();

    $q = Project::find($id)
    $q = $q->fill($data);
    $q->save();

    return response()->json([
        'code' => SUCCESS,
        'message' => 'Project data update successfully'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: no instead I use update() and then, I wrote Input::except('_token'); and then it worked, but I don't get why fill not worked...

Comment: @ChandniSoni Makes sense. `->fill()` will throw an error for any field trying to be updated which does not exist.

Comment: So is it happens because of the '_token'?

Comment: @ChandniSoni In this case yes. So its good to use `only()` or `except()` to filter out what you need (as you have done).

Comment: ok. Thank you so much for the information. I will implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method it will reduce your code

Route (api)

```
Route::post('UpdateProject/{project}','ProjectsController@UpdateProject');
```

`ProjectsController.php`

```
public function UpdateProject(Request $request, Project $project)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $project->update($data);
    return response()->json([
        'code' => SUCCESS,
        'message' => 'Project data update successfully'
    ]);
}
```